# Amazon MWS - How can I combine submit feed types in one request

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-mws

**Problem Scenario:**

I am working on an application that deals a lot with inventory prices and quantity, and also orders feed.

**What i need help with:**

I want to know if it is possible to combine feeds types such as that of prices **`(_POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_)`** and quantity **`(_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_)`** so that I won't surpass the request quota.

I using the *aws* library of *python 3.7*

Code of what I want:

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>************</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Inventory</MessageType>
<Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Inventory>
        <SKU>BUS999904</SKU>
        <Quantity>269</Quantity>
        <Price>10</Price>
    </Inventory>
</Message>
<Message>
    <MessageID>2</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Inventory>
        <SKU>PROBS-HO-01</SKU>
        <Quantity>137</Quantity>
        <Price>30</Price>
    </Inventory>
</Message>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code ? That'll provide some context with what you are facing issue with

Comment: thnx, I added it

Comment: I assume you're doing this so that you don't cap your quota?

Comment: So instead of : `<Quantity>269</Quantity>` `<Price>10</Price>` You want a single tag like `<QuantityandPrice></QuantityandPrice>` ?

Comment: No, amazon allows only either <Quantity>269</Quantity> with  _POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_ or <Price>10</Price> with _POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_ i want to be able to update both quantity and price with 1 request

Answer (score 0):

These are two separate feed types and there isn't a way to combine.  Take a look at the xsd's, there is a lot more data in each feed than just price and quantity.  Read the section, if you haven't already, on [maximizing feed performance](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_SubmitFeed.html).

The initial loading of all products might take some time and max out the quotas, but once you have your products and prices set, you just space out your updates every xx minutes and only update the products where there is a change.  Load more data in each feed to avoid throttling.

This is what I've done in the past and have had success selling 10,000+ different skus.